# Pythonic way to implement repetitive functions with decorators

Tags: python

```
@mydecorator('foo')
def foo():
    logic('foo')
    return True

@mydecorator('bar')
def bar():
    logic('bar')
    return True

@mydecorator('lorem')
def lorem():
    logic('lorem')
    return True

@mydecorator('ipsum')
def ipsum():
    logic('ipsum')
    return True

@mydecorator('abc')
def abc():
    logic('abc')
    return True

@mydecorator('xyz')
def xyz():
    logic('xyz')
    return True
```

Notice the pattern and repetitiveness?
Say I have a list `['foo','bar','lorem','ipsum','abc','xyz']`, how can achieve the same effect as the above code snippet in a less repetitive manner?

I obtain this list from a DB, I need the flexibility of adding/removing more items in this list and achieving the corresponding effect.

NOTE: I'm operating within several framework/architecture constraints, so yes, "if you're having to do this it's bad architecture", but this is what I need to do. I wonder if it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's in your `mydecorator` nor `logic` but my method could be transferred to it. This is a more "pythonic" way of doing what you want:

```
from functools import wraps

def mydecorator(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        print("In mydecorator: called by: "+func.__name__)
        return func(func.__name__, *args, **kwargs)
    return decorated

@mydecorator
def foo(name):
    logic(name)
    return True

@mydecorator
def bar(name):
    logic(name)
    return True

@mydecorator
def lorem(name):
    logic(name)
    return True

@mydecorator
def ipsum(name):
    logic(name)
    return True


def logic(name):
    print("In logic: called by: "+name)
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a nested-def to create closures that factor-out the common code.  Then, use *map()* to apply the function to the various fixed arguments:

```
def make_decorated(s):
    def inner():
        logic(s)
        return True
    return mydecorator(s)(inner)

foo, bar, lorem, ipsum = map(make_decorated, ['foo', 'bar', 'lorem', 'ipsum'])
```